# Excel 2007 Macro Recorded Pivot Table

Tags: excel

I recorded a macro in excel 2007 in which I created a pivot table. When i tried to
run the macro, I get "invalid procedure call or argument".

I looked at the debug window the "problem code" is:-

```
ActiveWorkbook.PivotCaches.Create(SourceType:=xlDatabase, SourceData:= _
"Data!R1C6:R15874C11", Version:=xlPivotTableVersion12).CreatePivotTable _
TableDestination:="Table!R1C1", TableName:="PivotTable7", _
DefaultVersion:=xlPivotTableVersion12
```

How can a recorded macro that do not work again? (I have cleared, removed and recreated the destination sheet and all sorts) and what is wrong with the macro itself ?

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried breaking the code down to see more specifically where the problem lies?

For example,

```
Dim pvc As PivotCache
Set pvc = ActiveWorkbook.PivotCaches.Create(SourceType:=xlDatabase, SourceData:= _
                                            "Data!R1C6:R15874C11", _
                                            Version:=xlPivotTableVersion12)
pvc.CreatePivotTable TableDestination:=Worksheets("Table").Range("A1"), _
                     TableName:="PivotTable7", DefaultVersion:=xlPivotTableVersion12
```

Also, perhaps try

```
Worksheets("Table").Range("A1")
```

instead of

```
"Table!R1C1"
```

Not sure if that will make any difference though...

Have you also checked:

There isn't a pivot table underneath where you are trying to create this one?

There are suitable headings for the pivot field names in row 1, columns 6 to 11?

I know you said you've recreated the sheet etcetera, but always worth checking there isn't a pivot table floating around... try:

```
Dim pvt As PivotTable
For Each pvt In Worksheets("Table").PivotTables
    Debug.Print pvt.Name
    Debug.Print pvt.TableRange2.Address
    pvt.ClearTable
    pvt.TableRange2.Clear
Next pvt
```

Other than that, I'm afraid I'm stumped.

Edit:

```
Sub ChangeSourceData()
    Worksheets("Table").PivotTables("PivotTable7").SourceData = "Data!R1C1:R25C6" 
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. It works. I need to clear the table 1st before re-creating it.

Comment: How can I update the data, especially SourceData:= "Data!R1C6:R15874C11", as it varies ? R1C6 is fixed but not for R15874C11.

Comment: Try using, for example:   Worksheets("Table").PivotTables("PivotTable7").SourceData = "Data!R1C1:R25C6"   or    Worksheets("Table").PivotTables(1).SourceData = "Data!R1C1:R25C6"

Comment: Nope, it doesn't work. I tried both. I added it as Set pvc = ActiveWorkbook.PivotCaches.Create(SourceType:=xlDatabase, Worksheets("Table").PivotTables("PivotTable7").SourceData:= _
        "DATA!R1C1:R25C6", Version:=xlPivotTableVersion12)

Comment: You shouldn't need to recreate the pivot cache, you can just change this for the table. See edit to my post...

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have:

A sheet named Data

A sheet named Table

No other pivot tables named PivotTable7